# Prevent user from typing in input at max value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like the user to be blocked from typing more if the value is over 100. So far I have the following from reading different posts:

```
$('.equipCatValidation').keyup(function(e){
        if ($(this).val() > 100) {               
           e.preventDefault();                
        }
    });
```

To confirm I want the value not the string length, and it can't be above 100.

However this is not preventing further input in the field. What am I missing.

Comment: Do you mean value or string length?

Comment: Think *really carefully* about whether or not that's a good idea. If the user types a value that is `>100`, then they don't have a way to edit it anymore. Not even to make it `<100`.

Comment: Really good point Matt.

Comment: Replace that part with : `$(this).val().length`

Comment: why not `maxlength` attribute.

Comment: maxlength?  that would be enforced by the browser and be independent of javascript.

Comment: @Scorpion OP did not confirm that it was string length.

Comment: @Anthony, also do you mean that this value **can't** be over 100?

Comment: Value 100. Said that in description.

Comment: @Anthony, When the value is over 100, it's still visible and then you are updating the textbox which is actually not preventing user from typing values more than 100. I suggest you try this way, http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/A5U2m/ . You can check my answer below.

Comment: @Ashad I like your method but I think from a user experience perspective it seems too restrictive to only be able to type 2 characters if the val is more than 100 (I kind of like the reset feedback you see in my example). I could add the message and border and it may seem better. I'll play around with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Checking keyup is too late, the event of adding the character has already happened. You need to use keydown. But you also want to make sure the value isn't > 100 so you do need to also use keyup to allow js to check the value then too.

You also have to allow people to delete the value, otherwise, once it's > 100 nothing can be changed.

```
<input class="equipCatValidation" type="number" />
```

When using input type="number", change also needs to be on the event list.

```
$('.equipCatValidation').on('keydown keyup change', function(e){
    if ($(this).val() > 100 
        && e.keyCode !== 46 // keycode for delete
        && e.keyCode !== 8 // keycode for backspace
       ) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $(this).val(100);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c8Lsvzdk/

Comment: The value can't be over 100. So if the user enters 101 entering more text should be prevented. Nice call on delete and backspace but i'm still able to enter values more than 100.

Comment: Will e.keyCode != 46 and e.keyCode != 8 behave the same on mobile devices?

Comment: @Anthony mobile devices that you're looking at a webpage with yes of course.

Comment: I am trying to prevent the user by entering 0 by just changing the condition "$(this).val() > 100 " to "$(this).val() < 0 ", but it also preventing entering other single digit number(i.e from 2 to 9) as well.Why so?Can any one help me with this?

Comment: If dealing with attributes such as value, min and max remember to use `parseInt($('selector').val())` as it may recognise it as a string and not an integer resulting in a bad conditional comparison.

Comment: Don't forget about arrow keys! People might want to "arrow left/right" to adjust their input.

Comment: You should add keycode for TAB key (switch to next input) in case there are multiple fields for data entry.

Answer (score 6):

Basically keypress events are fired before accepting the current value. So when you press on any key, keypress event is subscribed but you don't get the updated value/result for the recently pressed key. So, to get the last pressed key we can use the **fromCharCode** method and concat it with the value we got from the textbox. That's it,

HTML :

```
<input id="inputBox" type="text" />
```

jQuery :

```
$("#inputBox").on("keypress", function(e){
    var currentValue = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    var finalValue = $(this).val() + currentValue;
    if(finalValue > 100){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/A5U2m)

Comment: Annoying thing about this is if you select the text in the input then type to overwrite then it do only works if the current number plus the number you type is less than the total. So if you enter 10 and then select it and then type 1 instead of overwriting it stops you because finalValue is 101. Is there a way to handle selected?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe `keydown` instead of `keyup`?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(function() {

    $('.equipCatValidation').keydown(function(e){
      if ($(this).val() > 100) {            
         e.preventDefault();              
      }
    });

  })
  </script>

</head>
<body>

<input type="text" class="equipCatValidation">

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: There is a valid comment here - [Prevent user from typing in input at max value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24271242/prevent-user-from-typing-in-input-at-max-value/24271325#comment37498108_24271242) - to circumvent that you should probably store the previous value and restore it when necessary.

Answer (score 1):

It is bad UI to disable the input if a user inputs a bad value. I'm assuming you simply want to put a max value that the user cannot go over. If so, you can either clamp the value, or use the `max` attribute in your markup:

```
  <form>
    <input type='number' max='100'>
  </form>
```

If you input an invalid value, the input will turn red, and you cannot submit the form.

Comment: This is good but if the browser doesn't support `type=number` it will become a text field and there will be nothing to prevent the undesired result. Maybe using this and a js addon to add this functionality to those browsers that don't support it is the correct method.

Comment: Users can type anything in the box.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input class="equipCatValidation" />
var maxValue = 100;
```

*jquery*

```
$('.equipCatValidation').on('keypress', function(e){
  /* preventing set value when it doesn't pass conditions*/
 e.preventDefault(); 
 var input = $(this);
 var value = Number(input.val());
 var key = Number(e.key);
 if (Number.isInteger(key)) {
     value = Number("" + value + key);
     if (value > maxValue) {
       return false;
     }
     /* if value < maxValue => set new input value 
     in this way we don't allow input multi 0 */
     $element.val(value);
 }
});
```

*vanilla js*

```
document.querySelector(".equipCatValidation")
 .addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var input = e.target;
  var value = Number(input.value);
  var key = Number(e.key);
  if (Number.isInteger(key)) {
    value = Number("" + value + key);
    if (value > maxValue) {
      return false;
    }
    input.value = value;
  }
 });
```

[example](https://codepen.io/olexandr24664/pen/vvaByQ)

addition to the [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24271242/prevent-user-from-typing-in-input-at-max-value/50423651#50423651)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.equipCatValidation').on('keypress', function(e){
    var $element = $(this);
    var value = Number($element.val());
    var key = Number(e.key);

    if (Number.isInteger(key)) {
        value = Number("" + value + key);
    }

    if (value > 100) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Please, explain your answer. Only code is not an aswer

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution for those using modern vanilla Javascript:

Just snap the value back down to the max when the user focuses away from the input.

You  would set the input to a number type and the max value

```
<input type="number" max="100">
```

and then add a function to the `onblur` method of the element

```
document.querySelector('input[max]').onblur = function (event) {
    // If the value is less than the max then stop
    if (Number(event.target.value) < event.target.max) return
    // Snap the value to the max
    event.target.value = event.target.max
}
```

You can also use `oninput` instead of `onblur` but that may cause the user to have to fight the input in certain situations.

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/thatguysam/v25m6yd7/)