# How to run regular expression in Keyup event with JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I have this regular expression that validates up to 10 integers a decimal point and up to 10 decimals, how can I implement this regular expression in a textbox so that if the validation is not met I mark an error or stop the writing

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#decimal').on('input', function(e) {
    if (/^(\d{1,10})(.\d{1,10})?$/i.test(this.value)) {
      alert("Ok");
    } else {
      alert("x");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <p>
    <input type="text" name="value" id="decimal" /><br />
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your regular expression already gets triggered; are you asking how you can stop further input if the input doesn't match the expression?

Comment: @ObsidianAge Yes, of course, but it is not working the regular expression because it doesn´t validate. 
Execute the code and you will see

Comment: Any reason you can't use the HTML ```pattern``` attribute? https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html5-form-validation-with-the-pattern-attribute--cms-25145

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend adjusting your expression so that the dot is its own group.
Otherwise, adding a dot will be invalid until the dot is followed by a digit.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#decimal').on('input', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (/^(\d{1,10})(\.?)(\d{1,10})?$/i.test(this.value)) {
      $this.removeClass('invalid');
    } else {
      $this.addClass('invalid');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.invalid {
  background-color: #FFCCCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="value" id="decimal">
```

If you are *requiring* the dot and following digit(s) before the input is considered valid, then remove the question marks, which make their proceeding tokens optional:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#decimal').on('input', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (/^\d{1,10}\.\d{1,10}$/i.test(this.value)) {
      $this.removeClass('invalid');
    } else {
      $this.addClass('invalid');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.invalid {
  background-color: #FFCCCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="value" id="decimal">
```

---

Per your comment, you can prevent invalid characters from being typed.
The problem is that the [`input` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) cannot be cancelled.

The [`keypress` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress) can be cancelled, but fires before the last character is accepted. So, you'll need to build the final test value string based on the current value plus the appended current character.

The problem here is that you'll be able to enter more than 10 digits because the `.` is optional. So I've changed the regex to match 1-10 digits optionally followed by a dot OR a dot followed by 1-10 digits.

The problem now is that if the user types 10 digits and then selects them all, expecting that the next digit entered will erase the previous 10, it will fail because the handler still sees the value as being 10 digits even though those digits will be replaced.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#decimal').on('keypress', function(e) {
    var pressed = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    var final = this.value + pressed;
    if (!final.match(/^\d{1,10}(\.|\.\d{1,10})?$/i)) {
      e.preventDefault(); // or return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="value" id="decimal">
```

For more reference, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24271747/924299) by [Ashad Shanto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1174106/ashad-shanto).

Comment: and so that it is not possible to write when the textbox appears in red, the event that is used is event event.preventDefault()?

Answer (score 1):

Your regex has a problem, when you enter a `dot`, then it doesn't match.

I suggest you change the regex to the following:

```
^\d{1,10}\.?\d{0,10}$
```

Now it will match when you enter numbers with or without dot.

Note that I have ***escaped the dot***. Otherwise it Means '`Any character`', not just a dot.

I have also  changed to allow `0-10 digits` after the dot, otherwise it's impossible to enter the `dot`.

**EDit**:

if you want to accept number with up to 20 digits without a dot, use this:

```
^\d{1,10}\.?\d{0,10}$|^\d{1,20}$
```

It uses the OR operator '`|`' to give an alternative regex which will match 1 to 20 digits without a dot.

Comment: but if you do not wear a point, accept up to 20 characters, 
How can I do for when I do not wear a point? Just accept 10 digits